# java: package jakarta.persistence does not exist

Tags: java, persistence

I'm trying to use @Entity and @Id on another part of my project, but I need the error "java: package jakarta.persistence does not exist" to be resolved first. I've been working on this all day, but I really haven't gotten anywhere. I'm using Gradle and below are my dependencies. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Please let me know if you need more information.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.*group-name*'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.2.0'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.32'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:22.0.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.4.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.1.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:2.0.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:2.0.1'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:3.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.2.0'
}

jar {
    archiveFileName = "${project.name}-${project.version}.jar"
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I've tried adding new dependencies, checking all versions to make sure they're up to date, and I've altered the structure of my files to make sure that the right files were in the right places. I also tried invalidating caches, and adding my src to the listing of libraries.

Comment: What IDE are you using?  Or is this happening when you build from the command line?

Comment: (For Eclipse, try rerunning `gradle eclipse` to update the project's classpath.)

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but if you're using Spring Boot, you should let Spring Boot manage the dependencies (especially the versions), instead of doing it yourself. Also, you're specifying dependencies which the Spring Boot starters already pull in for you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel is right. All those `jakarta.*` dependencies should be removed as these are also transitive dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-validation`. The same goes for `hibernate-core`.

Comment: I'm using the IntelliJ community version @StephenC. I removed the Jarkarta and hibernate-core dependencies, but the problem persists.

Comment: Does this happening when you build from the command line?

Comment: Yes, it does. I've tried using the ./gradlew build command, and it fails out on a test I haven't worked on yet. It gives me the error message: 
*Myproject*Tests > contextLoads() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1775
            Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException at AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421
                Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException at StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:63
                    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException at SQLError.java:130

Comment: That is an entirely different error than the one in your post (a runtime error instead of a compiletime error), which means the problem goes away when you run gradle itself. It sounds that you need to reimport/refresh Gradle in IntelliJ (the refresh button in the Gradle tab) so it updates the dependencies. Or you haven't actually created the IntelliJ project as a Gradle project, so the dependencies in your build.gradle are not actually used to configure IntelliJ.

Comment: I made sure that Gradle is installed in the plugins menu in settings, but there is no Gradle tab present so I can't reimport Gradle. I have rebuilt the project multiple times during this process though. I've tried to make sure that it's a created as a Gradle project, but I'm not sure how to tell whether it is or not. I have all the proper gradle files in my project structure, and, as far as I can tell, all the right plugins on my build.gradle file.

Comment: I commented out the "tasks.named('test')" and the project had a successful build from the terminal, but most of my annotations still aren't recognized. In case it helps, here's a list of some of the annotations that won't load successfully in my project:
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest; - "springframework isn't recognized, 
"@SpringBootTest", 
import jakarta.persistence.Entity; - jakarta is uncrecognized, 
"@Entity", 
"@Id", 
"@SpringBootApplication", 
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication; - springframework is unrecognized